# Proper way to merge data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have 2 dataframes and would like to merge them into one. But they have common fields. Like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,3], 'C': [7,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3,4,5], 'B': [6,7,8]})
```

There are some merging criteria

1. Use Column A as a key to merge
2. If there are common columns, use `df1` and ignore the content in `df2`

So the result df would look like

```
   A  B    C
0  1  4  7.0
1  2  5  8.0
2  3  3  9.0
3  4  7  NaN
4  5  8  NaN
```

How should I write this merging equation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `A`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('A')
print (df)
   A  B    C
0  1  4  7.0
1  2  5  8.0
2  3  3  9.0
4  4  7  NaN
5  5  8  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then remove the duplicates on `'A'` column:

```
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)

mask = ~merged.duplicated('A')

print(merged[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   A  B    C
0  1  4  7.0
1  2  5  8.0
2  3  3  9.0
1  4  7  NaN
2  5  8  NaN
```